# yt-dlp turns off my Telegram and Discord when I use --download-sections

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, youtube-dl, macos-monterey, yt-dlp

I'm getting this problem on a macOS Monterey.

When I run yt-dlp --download-sections, it takes a few seconds to reach the frame downloading part, but when it does get there, my Discord gets stuck on loading screen and my Telegram gets the connecting loading thing on the top bar.

Internet still works though. I can still visit websites on Safari.

This is what I get when I run the command: yt-dlp 'link' --download-sections "*00:02:30-00:03:20" --force-keyframes-at-cuts --recode mov

```
[debug] Command-line config: ['link', '--download-sections', '*00:02:30-00:03:20', '--force-keyframes-at-cuts', '--recode', 'mov', '-vU']
[debug] User config "/Users/hellpillars/.config/yt-dlp/config.txt": ['-P', '/Volumes/SuperFastDavid/YtDownloads/', '-o', '%(title)s.%(ext)s', '--no-mtime']
[debug] Encodings: locale UTF-8, fs utf-8, pref UTF-8, out utf-8, error utf-8, screen utf-8
[debug] yt-dlp version stable@2023.03.04 [392389b7d] (zip)
[debug] Python 3.11.2 (CPython x86_64 64bit) - macOS-12.6.4-x86_64-i386-64bit (OpenSSL 1.1.1s  1 Nov 2022)
[debug] exe versions: ffmpeg 5.1.2 (setts), ffprobe 5.1.2
[debug] Optional libraries: certifi-2022.12.07, no_Cryptodome-None, sqlite3-2.6.0
[debug] Proxy map: {}
[debug] Loaded 1786 extractors
[debug] Fetching release info: https://api.github.com/repos/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/releases/latest
Available version: stable@2023.03.04, Current version: stable@2023.03.04
Current Build Hash: 91cad9f121c1f6f0a81b747415c46ecba0ff331ed38cc6433040b4ac7b6e15ca
yt-dlp is up to date (stable@2023.03.04)
[youtube] Extracting URL: link
[youtube] P_plHaeu4Os: Downloading webpage
[youtube] P_plHaeu4Os: Downloading android player API JSON
[debug] Sort order given by extractor: quality, res, fps, hdr:12, source, vcodec:vp9.2, channels, acodec, lang, proto
[debug] Formats sorted by: hasvid, ie_pref, quality, res, fps, hdr:12(7), source, vcodec:vp9.2(10), channels, acodec, lang, proto, filesize, fs_approx, tbr, vbr, abr, asr, vext, aext, hasaud, id
[debug] Default format spec: bestvideo*+bestaudio/best
[info] P_plHaeu4Os: Downloading 1 format(s): 313+251
[info] P_plHaeu4Os: Downloading 1 time ranges: 150.0-200.0
[debug] Invoking ffmpeg downloader on "https://rr3---sn-npa3oxu-ucns.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1680535623&ei=55sqZLX4N8LH1gKunprgCg&ip=178.134.95.227&id=o-ANi3XBwcKoAt7XJuhmjTITYOieRcJX1vPWk7h0yiJ86x&itag=313&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=MM&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-npa3oxu-ucns%2Csn-4g5edns7&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=3&pl=18&initcwndbps=1315000&spc=99c5CXKmVdu2lNlJTQ1Z2q-ImNmXuPc&vprv=1&svpuc=1&mime=video%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=7583345214&dur=4428.382&lmt=1679197208679333&mt=1680513673&fvip=3&keepalive=yes&fexp=24007246&c=ANDROID&txp=4432434&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Csvpuc%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRAIgN6BepoPC9J6siVb7Jekhm2nRKtj2XAMBEpNuwMxidzYCIAqS9Z0Iveyo4a60Qp5_dDbS-Kx7NJRo0lbjMQ_YrYLS&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRAIgMjWY4MfekekEQkUtQFPf58dgE4bc8AWr1MhyJMtpGO0CIC10Y4r3b5lDssWayIOBnEoB4u_37_DCHIGWhG2I-pM9", "https://rr3---sn-npa3oxu-ucns.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1680535623&ei=55sqZLX4N8LH1gKunprgCg&ip=178.134.95.227&id=o-ANi3XBwcKoAt7XJuhmjTITYOieRcJX1vPWk7h0yiJ86x&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=MM&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-npa3oxu-ucns%2Csn-4g5edns7&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=3&pl=18&initcwndbps=1315000&spc=99c5CXKmVdu2lNlJTQ1Z2q-ImNmXuPc&vprv=1&svpuc=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=61896170&dur=4428.421&lmt=1679190185997510&mt=1680513673&fvip=3&keepalive=yes&fexp=24007246&c=ANDROID&txp=4432434&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Csvpuc%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRgIhAO4kTUidCEdUfiYdeF6Muv82X107Mj0DHUee5hCfcDZTAiEA49wae_MbHwkCrPbRi2a7thcKfCreO4C2XB-O5jQlFSI%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRAIgMjWY4MfekekEQkUtQFPf58dgE4bc8AWr1MhyJMtpGO0CIC10Y4r3b5lDssWayIOBnEoB4u_37_DCHIGWhG2I-pM9"
[download] Destination: /Volumes/SuperFastDavid/YtDownloads/How to Be a High Value Woman ft @StirlingCooper ｜ Dailyrapupcrew Podcast Ep 96.webm
[debug] ffmpeg command line: ffmpeg -y -loglevel verbose -headers 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.70 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
' -ss 150.0 -t 50.0 -i 'https://rr3---sn-npa3oxu-ucns.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1680535623&ei=55sqZLX4N8LH1gKunprgCg&ip=178.134.95.227&id=o-ANi3XBwcKoAt7XJuhmjTITYOieRcJX1vPWk7h0yiJ86x&itag=313&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=MM&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-npa3oxu-ucns%2Csn-4g5edns7&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=3&pl=18&initcwndbps=1315000&spc=99c5CXKmVdu2lNlJTQ1Z2q-ImNmXuPc&vprv=1&svpuc=1&mime=video%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=7583345214&dur=4428.382&lmt=1679197208679333&mt=1680513673&fvip=3&keepalive=yes&fexp=24007246&c=ANDROID&txp=4432434&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Csvpuc%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRAIgN6BepoPC9J6siVb7Jekhm2nRKtj2XAMBEpNuwMxidzYCIAqS9Z0Iveyo4a60Qp5_dDbS-Kx7NJRo0lbjMQ_YrYLS&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRAIgMjWY4MfekekEQkUtQFPf58dgE4bc8AWr1MhyJMtpGO0CIC10Y4r3b5lDssWayIOBnEoB4u_37_DCHIGWhG2I-pM9' -headers 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.70 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
' -ss 150.0 -t 50.0 -i 'https://rr3---sn-npa3oxu-ucns.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1680535623&ei=55sqZLX4N8LH1gKunprgCg&ip=178.134.95.227&id=o-ANi3XBwcKoAt7XJuhmjTITYOieRcJX1vPWk7h0yiJ86x&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=MM&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-npa3oxu-ucns%2Csn-4g5edns7&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=3&pl=18&initcwndbps=1315000&spc=99c5CXKmVdu2lNlJTQ1Z2q-ImNmXuPc&vprv=1&svpuc=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=61896170&dur=4428.421&lmt=1679190185997510&mt=1680513673&fvip=3&keepalive=yes&fexp=24007246&c=ANDROID&txp=4432434&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Csvpuc%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRgIhAO4kTUidCEdUfiYdeF6Muv82X107Mj0DHUee5hCfcDZTAiEA49wae_MbHwkCrPbRi2a7thcKfCreO4C2XB-O5jQlFSI%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRAIgMjWY4MfekekEQkUtQFPf58dgE4bc8AWr1MhyJMtpGO0CIC10Y4r3b5lDssWayIOBnEoB4u_37_DCHIGWhG2I-pM9' -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -f webm 'file:/Volumes/SuperFastDavid/YtDownloads/How to Be a High Value Woman ft @StirlingCooper ｜ Dailyrapupcrew Podcast Ep 96.webm.part'
ffmpeg version 5.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2_6 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
[tcp @ 0x7fc394804c80] Starting connection attempt to 178.134.0.206 port 443
[tcp @ 0x7fc394804c80] Successfully connected to 178.134.0.206 port 443
[tcp @ 0x7fc393f06000] Starting connection attempt to 178.134.0.206 port 443
[tcp @ 0x7fc393f06000] Successfully connected to 178.134.0.206 port 443
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'https://rr3---sn-npa3oxu-ucns.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1680535623&ei=55sqZLX4N8LH1gKunprgCg&ip=178.134.95.227&id=o-ANi3XBwcKoAt7XJuhmjTITYOieRcJX1vPWk7h0yiJ86x&itag=313&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=MM&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-npa3oxu-ucns%2Csn-4g5edns7&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=3&pl=18&initcwndbps=1315000&spc=99c5CXKmVdu2lNlJTQ1Z2q-ImNmXuPc&vprv=1&svpuc=1&mime=video%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=7583345214&dur=4428.382&lmt=1679197208679333&mt=1680513673&fvip=3&keepalive=yes&fexp=24007246&c=ANDROID&txp=4432434&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Csvpuc%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRAIgN6BepoPC9J6siVb7Jekhm2nRKtj2XAMBEpNuwMxidzYCIAqS9Z0Iveyo4a60Qp5_dDbS-Kx7NJRo0lbjMQ_YrYLS&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRAIgMjWY4MfekekEQkUtQFPf58dgE4bc8AWr1MhyJMtpGO0CIC10Y4r3b5lDssWayIOBnEoB4u_37_DCHIGWhG2I-pM9':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : google/video-file
  Duration: 01:13:48.38, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 13699 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), 1 reference frame, yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
[tcp @ 0x7fc394829440] Starting connection attempt to 178.134.0.206 port 443
[tcp @ 0x7fc394829440] Successfully connected to 178.134.0.206 port 443
[tcp @ 0x7fc394805c00] Starting connection attempt to 178.134.0.206 port 443
[tcp @ 0x7fc394805c00] Successfully connected to 178.134.0.206 port 443
Input #1, matroska,webm, from 'https://rr3---sn-npa3oxu-ucns.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1680535623&ei=55sqZLX4N8LH1gKunprgCg&ip=178.134.95.227&id=o-ANi3XBwcKoAt7XJuhmjTITYOieRcJX1vPWk7h0yiJ86x&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=MM&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-npa3oxu-ucns%2Csn-4g5edns7&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=3&pl=18&initcwndbps=1315000&spc=99c5CXKmVdu2lNlJTQ1Z2q-ImNmXuPc&vprv=1&svpuc=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=61896170&dur=4428.421&lmt=1679190185997510&mt=1680513673&fvip=3&keepalive=yes&fexp=24007246&c=ANDROID&txp=4432434&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Csvpuc%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRgIhAO4kTUidCEdUfiYdeF6Muv82X107Mj0DHUee5hCfcDZTAiEA49wae_MbHwkCrPbRi2a7thcKfCreO4C2XB-O5jQlFSI%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRAIgMjWY4MfekekEQkUtQFPf58dgE4bc8AWr1MhyJMtpGO0CIC10Y4r3b5lDssWayIOBnEoB4u_37_DCHIGWhG2I-pM9':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : google/video-file
  Duration: 01:13:48.42, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 111 kb/s
  Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, delay 312 (default)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp9 (native) -> vp9 (libvpx-vp9))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (opus (native) -> opus (libopus))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7fc3948219c0] w:3840 h:2160 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000 fr:24000/1001 sar:1/1
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x7fc393f19c00] v1.13.0
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x7fc393f19c00] --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libvpx/1.13.0 --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-examples --disable-unit-tests --enable-pic --enable-shared --enable-vp9-highbitdepth --enable-runtime-cpu-detect
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x7fc393f19c00] Neither bitrate nor constrained quality specified, using default CRF of 32
[graph_1_in_1_0 @ 0x7fc398e076c0] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:stereo
[format_out_0_1 @ 0x7fc398e08bc0] auto-inserting filter 'auto_aresample_0' between the filter 'Parsed_anull_0' and the filter 'format_out_0_1'
[auto_aresample_0 @ 0x7fc394d0a880] ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:fltp r:48000Hz -> ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:flt r:48000Hz
[libopus @ 0x7fc393f1b240] No bit rate set. Defaulting to 96000 bps.
Output #0, webm, to 'file:/Volumes/SuperFastDavid/YtDownloads/How to Be a High Value Woman ft @StirlingCooper ｜ Dailyrapupcrew Podcast Ep 96.webm.part':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9, 1 reference frame, yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 3840x2160 (0x0) [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 23.98 fps, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libvpx-vp9
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, flt, delay 312, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libopus
frame=    1 fps=0.2 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   Automatically inserted bitstream filter 'vp9_superframe'; args=''
frame=   25 fps=3.8 q=10.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.04 bitrate= 126.0kbits/frame=   28 fps=3.9 q=32.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.17 bitrate=  31.1kbits/frame=   31 fps=4.0 q=30.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:00.29 bitrate=  18.4kbits/frame=   34 fps=4.0 q=32.0 size=
```

I tried installing newer versions of FFmpeg, didn't really fix much, but when I do --downloader ffmpeg without --download-sections it downloads without problem.